# Objective-C casting of custom classes

Tags: objective-c, class, casting, instancetype

Let say I have a custom class named as:

```
classA
```

and I have another custom class named as:

```
classB
```

How could I cast classA to classB?

Comment: You need to provide more context. Does one class inherit from the other? Show a real example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way as C/C++:

```
ClassA* objectA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
ClassB* objectB = (ClassB*) objectA;
```